# Pycharm with Django throws ImportError: cannot import name 'unittest'

Tags: django, pycharm, django-testing

I am working through the Django tutorial, and am trying to get the test cases to run with PyCharm. I have encountered a problem however. When I run the command: `app test`

I am faced with this exception: test framework quit unexpectedly:

```
F:\programming\Python\python.exe "F:\programming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.4\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py" test a F:\programming\Projects\pycharm\untitled
Testing started at 4:54 PM ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\programming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.4\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py", line 157, in <module>
    utility.execute()
  File "F:\programming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.4\helpers\pycharm\django_test_manage.py", line 110, in execute
    from django_test_runner import is_nosetest
  File "F:\programming\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.2.4\helpers\pycharm\django_test_runner.py", line 42, in <module>
    from django.utils import unittest
ImportError: cannot import name 'unittest'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Apparently, the `django_test_manage.py` file does not work. How can I fix this?
this happens even when the `test.py` class is empty. So it must be a problem with PyCharm then(?)
I am using PyCharm Pro 2017.2.4, Django 2.0 and Python 3.6
My run/debug configurations are just the basic, preset Django Settings that PyCharm does.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're looking at the wrong version of the tutorial? This is the version for django 2.0 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial05/

Comment: no, it is the right one. But regardless of my testcases, i can't run tests at all ( even if the tests.py class is empty, i get the same error)

Comment: Installed the 2018.2 version I was on 2017 version, and it's failing to import a submodule in a project for me - python 2.7 . Just the debugger is causing the pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new PyCharm has this bug fixed.

If update PyCharm is not an option, you can change the following lines on `django_test_runner.py`:

```
 if VERSION[1] >= 7:
   import unittest
 else:
   from django.utils import unittest
```

to:

```
 if VERSION >= (1, 7):
   import unittest
 else:
   from django.utils import unittest
```

Again at line 56 change to:

```
if VERSION >= (1, 6):
```

And finally at line 256 change to:

```
if VERSION >= (1, 1):
```

Why?  Because the `VERSION` refers to the version of django, which has ticked over to `2` point something.

Comment: Also in the file there's `if VERSION[1] >= 6:` which should be replaced with `if VERSION >= (1, 6):`, and `if VERSION[1] >= 1:` which should be replaced with `if VERSION >= (1, 1):`, and everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 6):

`django.utils.unittest` was removed in Django 1.9 So I suspect you may be using an old version of the tutorial.

In pycharm are you using the `django.tests.testcases` run config? Better to use the Python `unittest.TestCase` as detailed [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206602245-Uprade-Django-1-6-5-to-1-7-tests-not-working-now)

edit: So in [django_test_runner.py](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/python/helpers/pycharm/django_test_runner.py) you have the following:

```
from django.test.testcases import TestCase
from django import VERSION

# See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.7/#django-utils-unittest
# django.utils.unittest provided uniform access to the unittest2 library on all Python versions.
# Since unittest2 became the standard library's unittest module in Python 2.7,
# and Django 1.7 drops support for older Python versions, this module isn't useful anymore.
# It has been deprecated. Use unittest instead.
if VERSION >= (1,7):
  import unittest
else:
  from django.utils import unittest
```

So it appears that the version of django that you are using in the intepreter for your test runconfig is < 1.7 (when `django.utils.unittest` was deprecated.) What is returned if you do `from django import VERSION` and print it in your interpreter?

Comment: im not calling unittest, pycharm is, in its django_test_runner.py class

Comment: also can you point me to where it says that unittests were removed? 
it says here that they are the prefered way:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20680 The unittest library it recommends is the PYTHON standard library unittest (see the link on the page you posted) not the inbuilt django.utils.unittest library which was a copy and has been removed

Comment: using unittest.TestCase instead of Django.test testcases still throws the same error.

Comment: im using a virtualenv with django 2.0rc1

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bug in django_test_runner.py of Pycharm.

In my pycharm, the code is :

```
  if VERSION[1] >= 7:
    import unittest
  else:
    from django.utils import unittest
```

But you (and i) use Django 2.0, so pycharm import  'from django.utils import unittest' ...

I have modified my test_runner like that :

```
  if VERSION[0] > 1 or VERSION[1] >= 7:
    import unittest
  else:
    from django.utils import unittest
```

You need modify the same file in other places with the same tricks.

It's work !

Comment: A better approach would be `if VERSION >= (1, 7)`. Since your code would import incorrectly for django below 1.7.

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.test.simple'

Answer (score 1):

There is actually more problems with `django_test_runner.py`. What helped was to replace it with this version: https://gist.github.com/IlianIliev/6f884f237ab52d10aa0e22d53df97141

It can be found in `<pycharm_root>/helpers/pycharm`